# How do i change the grid floor?

Tags: modeling

I'm making a small object and it is bit difficult to see what i'm doing.

Usally i just open the N-panel and change it under Display, but can't find that option in the new Blender 3.0 Beta.

I want to make the grid floor smaller.

I want to change the scale to 0.1

Comment: "*in the new Blender 3.0 Beta.*" Time travel is possible after all! What year are you writing from? Blender 2.8 is barely into beta here

Answer (score 2):

Check out the overlays drop down menu :

[image]