# Add Object Comes Tiny Only For Default Objects

Tags: mesh, objects

When I launch Blender it comes with a perfect 2x2x2m cube. But when I <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>A</kbd>  *Mesh>Cube* it appends a cube at 0.002x0.002x0.002m.

The strange thing is that when I add for example, a diamond or an empty it comes ok with the perfect size of around 2m.

As I understand the objects that are from the addons Add mesh & Add curve append perfectly. Only the default objects like sphere,cube,torus etc. come tiny.[image: example][image: settings][image: settings2]

Is there a way to resolve this and when appending a cube to be 2x2x2m without reinstalling ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i change the grid floor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129259/how-do-i-change-the-grid-floor)

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved, all i was needed to change was the Grid Scale like shown in picute here

[How do i change the grid floor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129259/how-do-i-change-the-grid-floor)